# Trying to get property of non-object SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I've tried multiple combinations of code, and even when I thought I had the grasp of it, it failed! I always come back to a "get property of non-object error" my current one is:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in {PROJECT_DIR} on line 11
```

Anyways, I'm attempting to change the node value of a bookmark in a .docx files document.xml file and I've got an array of bookmark id's => bookmark names and I am looping through them using a simple foreach to edit all found bookmarks using SimpleXML, however, I'm having a bit of a problem with it.

My current code is:

```
if (file_exists('document.xml'))
{
    $document = simplexml_load_file('document.xml');
}
echo $document->getName() . "<br />";
echo $document->document->body->{'w:bookmarkStart'};
```

I've tried removing the ->document from the echo statement and changing {'w:bookmarkStart'} to bookmarkStart but all has proven ineffective, however the above changes I said I attempted did not return a notice, just blank.
I'm sure I haven't got the 'gist of this XML thing yet, and I am rather noob-ish at it and it'd probably be an easy to point out problem for you guys but research and usage of code examples has proven ineffective for me ;(
A compact version of the XML file I am attempting to edit is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
            xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
            xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
            xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
            xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
            xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
            xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
            xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
            xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
            xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:body>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="MOREG"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help? 
`$document->xpath("//w:bookmarkEnd");`
Using xpath query may be more practical and it works fine to select the node.
(Maybe someone here can help you find a way to do it the way you are doing it ,sorry if this isn't helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, namespaces (the `<w:...` notation and `xmlns:w="..."` declaration in your example) make SimpleXML rather less simple.

The first thing to know is that the `w:` prefix is actually just a local alias for the "real" namespace, which is the URI defined by the corresponding `xmlns:w` attribute - in this case, `'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'`

The second thing to know is that to get elements in anything other than the default (un-prefixed) namespace, you need to use the SimpleXML methods [`->children($namespace)`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [`->attributes($namespace)`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

So with a bit of trial-and-error, I got your example XML to output "MOREG" using the following:

```
$w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main';
echo $document->children($w)->body->bookmarkStart['name'];
```

If you are using PHP ≥ 5.2, you can actually make use of the 'w' prefix by passing `true` to the `children` method, simplifying things to this:

```
echo $document->children('w', TRUE)->body->bookmarkStart['name'];
```